# In directive, I can not get to the `getUser` method located in authService

Tags: angularjs

In directive, I can not get to the `getUser` method located in authService:

```
    angular.module('app').directive('guard', [ function ( authService) {

        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            link: function (scope, element, attrs) {

           //     element.hide();

                function currentUserHasAnyPermission(requiredP) {
                    return authService.getUser().then(function (currentUser) {
                       var currentUserP = currentUser.permissions;
                        return _.intersection(currentUserP, requiredP).length > 0;
                    });
                }
            }
        };

    }]);
```

Returns an error:

```
Cannot read property 'getUser' of undefined
   at currentUserHasAnyPermission
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove the square brackets:

```
̶a̶n̶g̶u̶l̶a̶r̶.̶m̶o̶d̶u̶l̶e̶(̶'̶a̶p̶p̶'̶)̶.̶d̶i̶r̶e̶c̶t̶i̶v̶e̶(̶'̶g̶u̶a̶r̶d̶'̶,̶ ̶[̶ ̶f̶u̶n̶c̶t̶i̶o̶n̶ ̶(̶ ̶a̶u̶t̶h̶S̶e̶r̶v̶i̶c̶e̶)̶ ̶{̶ 
angular.module('app').directive('guard', function ( authService) {

    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {

       //     element.hide();

            function currentUserHasAnyPermission(requiredP) {
                return authService.getUser().then(function (currentUser) {
                   var currentUserP = currentUser.permissions;
                    return _.intersection(currentUserP, requiredP).length > 0;
                });
            }
        }
    };

̶}̶]̶)̶;̶
});
```

For more information, see [AngularJS Developer Guide - Implicit Dependency Injection](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di#implicit-annotation)

Comment: I deleted but returns an error: `TypeError: authService.getUser(...).then is not a function`

Comment: Yea. Progress. Then the next step is to look at the `authService` factory. Are you really asking the internet to debug your program? Today is a good day to learn how to debug things for yourself. See [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: okey, How to correctly call `currentUserHasAnyPermission` functions
eturns an error:
`currentUserHasAnyPermission (...). then is not a function`

Comment: in this line
 `element.hide();`
  also gives me a error:
`element.hide is not a function`

Comment: why I can not call a function `element.hide();` in this directive?

Comment: You need to add jquery to your page if you need `hide`. AngularJS has a built-in subset of jquery called jqlite. It does not provide `hide` function.